# Unable to set button location in WPF

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to set the position of my button but whenever I do something like

```
leftButton.Location = new Point(1, 1);
```

I get "'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found". Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF elements don't have a "Location" property because elements are positioned based on their container.

For example, if you place a Button inside a `Grid`, you position it using the Grid's layout system (eg. Row, Column, RowSpan, ColumnSpan, etc) and then fine tune its position with the Button's `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment`, `VerticalAlignment` properties. So inside a Grid example, "Location" doesn't mean anything.

There is a container that does what you're trying to do though, called a `Canvas`. If you place a Button inside a Canvas, you can control the Button's "Location" similar to what you're trying to do.

For example, in XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="50">Click me</Button>
</Canvas>
```

In C# code:

```
Button button = new Button {Content = "Click me"};
Canvas.SetLeft(button, 20);
Canvas.SetTop(button, 50);

canvas.Children.Add(button);
```

Note that using a Canvas is generally not a great way to create UIs in WPF. `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `UniformGrid`, and others are much better at creating complex UI layouts and don't require any C# code for most use cases. It's also a good idea to do as much as you can using XAML and use C# code if you need to for things you can't achieve in XAML.